# ERROR: relation "replication_test" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres, and getting error

```
ERROR:  relation "replication_test" does not exist
```

The table does exist.. I am trying following command

```
/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql -dpgdb  -Udunkin -h localhost 
            -c "select * from replication_test;"
```

dunkin user has access to pgdb database and is superuser
when I execute following

```
/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/psql -dpgdb  -Udunkin -h localhost
```

I am able to successfully login to database.

Please provide some pointers

Comment: Who is the schema that is owner of this table ?! try to put the schema name with the table name: `schemaName.replication_test`

Comment: If the table was created with a quoted identifier, you will need to also quote the identifier in your queries. You may try: `select * from "replication_test";`

Comment: So is there a table with that name in `pgdb`?

Comment: tried that as well and getting same error, even checked for the letter case